# Cannot return Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, typeorm

I'm using `Typeorm` so I've created a method that return a connection:

```
public static async getConnection(): Promise<Connection> {
    if (DatabaseProvider.connection) {
        return DatabaseProvider.connection;
    }

    const { type, host, port, username, password, database, extra, entities, migrations } = DatabaseProvider.configuration;
    DatabaseProvider.connection = await createConnection({
        type, host, port, username, password, database,
        extra,
        entities: [
            entities
        ],
        migrations: [
            migrations
        ]
    } as any); 

    return DatabaseProvider.connection;
}
```

I want assign the `connection` to a bot instance of `Telegraf` so I have created a `.d.ts` file for specify the type:

```
export interface TelegrafContext extends Context {
    db: Connection
}
```

then:

```
bot.context.db = DatabaseProvider.getConnection().then((conn) => { return conn; });
```

and I get:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Connection': name, options, isConnected, driver, and 32 more.

What I did wrong?

Comment: `then()` does return another promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you're trying to assign `Promise<Connection>` to `bot.context.db` and it should be a `Connection`.

so you can either:

```
DatabaseProvider.getConnection().then((conn) => { 
  bot.context.db = conn
});
```

or:

```
bot.context.db = await DatabaseProvider.getConnection()
```

Comment: is possible resolve the `Promise` in `then` directly? Why I can't simply return `conn` from `then`? Is it returning another `Promise`?

Comment: @sfarzoso yes, `.then()` is returning another promise

Comment: is not possible resolve the `Promise` in `.then()`?